# Date picker bootstrap work only first time

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have datepiker

```
 <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Publish date:</label>
                    <div class="controls">

                        <div class="input-append date form_datetime">
                            <input size="16" type="text" readonly 
   value="<%=Item!=null?Item.PublishDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"):                     
     DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") %>" id="PublishDate" 
     name="PublishDate" class="m-wrap" data-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
           <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

first time work normal  [image]

but second time something not good [image]

here I init the datepiker

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".form_datetime").datepicker({
                isRTL: false,
                format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                pickerPosition: "bottom-left",
                autoclose: true
            });
});
```

Maybe problem is in init?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the script you mentioned class name as "form_datetime", but you gave  tag class as "m-wrap". Assign same class name and try again..